# random numbers in start of multi-term prompt when using zsh

Tags: emacs, zsh

Below is the prompt that I see when I use zsh with the multi-term in emacs. What are the numbers that I see before the dir and how do I get rid of them ?

> \342\236\234 ~/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the UTF-8 encoding of the U+279C HEAVY ROUND-TIPPED RIGHTWARDS ARROW Unicode character (➜), whose bytes are output in octal:

```
$ printf '\342\236\234\n'
➜
```

So, it seems that the multi-term in Emacs doesn't support UTF-8 (or check your locales and your settings). You can redefine the prompt by setting the `PS1` variable. For instance:

```
PS1="%m%#"
```

(see the zshmisc(1) man page for the prompt sequences).